# Epanechnikov kernel and GCV

Tags: r, nonparametric, matlab

Does anyone know how to select bandwidth with GCV for Epanechnikov kernel in R or Matlab?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If by select you mean get the used value, here is how to do it:

```
[f,xi,bw] = ksdensity(x); 
bw
```

Found in [this documentation](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/stats/ksdensity.html#btppv_k-1).